# Separate 1 large column into 2 small columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to turn 1 large column (column A with a row length of x+y rows) into into 2 small columns (column B with a row length of x rows and column C with a row length of y rows, where the contents of the cells have not changed) in R.

Here is the illustration of the data:

```
Original Column:
    Column A <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
New Columns after r code is run:
    Column B <- c("1", "2", "3")
    Column C <- c("4", "5", "6", "7")
```

Hos to generate column C?

Comment: Is the condition on splitting the vector only based on whether the value is greater than 3 or less than 4? And is there a reason you have the values set to character?

Comment: Not clear. Are you trying to say that you start with a column vector, say `A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` and a subset of that, say `B=c(1,2,3)`, and you want the output to be the vector `C=c(4,5,6,7)`, which is what's remaining in A after removing B?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Sorry for the cloudiness. The illustration is just an example with made up data. I would like to do this with any form or data in place of the numbers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your condition is: (e.g. `as.numeric(Column_A) < 4`)

```
Column_B <- Column_A[condition]
Column_C <- Column_A[!condition]
```